# Delete all lines between XML 2 lines

Tags: xml

How to delete all lines between 2 lines?

```
<integer id="database_table_type" value="3"/>
<large id="db_unique_id" value="2065455306626279641"/>
<integer id="property" value="1416326961"/>
```

Lines 1 and 3 are same but line 2 is different because that value number.

Comment: 1) modifying Xml should not be done "deleting lines". 2) line 1 and line 3 are not the same 3) all value attributes are different

Comment: You should provide some context to your problem - it looks like you are overcomplicating a trivial task of selecting some elements from an Xml document.

Comment: line 1 is always same in whole file. line 3 also. just line 2 is different. problem is i cant delete all lines with                <large id="db_unique_id" value=          only lines between lines 1 and 3. is there some way to do it?

Comment: As I already said: Provide the context for this Xml structure and look into selecting the desired elements by xpath queries or create a new Xml document by transforming it using Xslt. Both solution depend on the programming language and/or platform you are using which you also didn't mention yet. Please provide the full context for your problem or nobody will be able to help you. Currently I could answer your question by telling you to highlight the desired lines in your editor an press "Del" but this is surely not what you are looking for.

Comment: XML does not have lines. That XML would be exactly the same thing if there were no newlines at all.